# Validation loss and accuracy not changing from training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm using transfer learning with MobileNet v2 with Tensorflow 2.0 to train a network for skin quality classification. Everything is working perfectly fine, however it seems that the validation loss and validation accuracy do not change.

I've saved the model files and run predictions on a variety of images, but this also led to no success as the model outputs exactly the same predictions for every image.

[image: epoch outputs]

A very peculiar problem and google seems to have no answers for this. Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that can be one of several things:

1. You have mislabeled you data. The CNN can't learn because the labels are "random". This is probably the most probable cause. Check carefully that you have encoded your labels properly and loaded them correctly.
2. Your learning rate is too high and you have no lr schedule. This is also very common problem, especially when you take the configuration from 8 v100 gpu training and train it on 1 gpu. You need to adjust your lr accordingly.